# UITextField not to respond touches, but respond clear button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have `UITextField`, i need to make it not to respond touches, because it is located on the `UITableViewCell`, and when user touches the `textField`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not getting called.

This textField has also clear button, i need to detect user taping on the clear button only, not in the rest textField area.

I tried, `textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO`. In this case clear button doesn't work of course, the same is with `textField.enabled = NO;`

```
 UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
 textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
 textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
 textField.delegate = self;
```

Help, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{ return NO; }` will make textfield non editable.

Comment: Can the user edit the text in the textfield at all? If not, just use a `UILabel`, set user interaction off and add an accessory button to the table cell to trigger the clear action. When the user taps the accessory button, clear the label.

Comment: I implemented -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{ return NO; } , but textfield still responds to touches, i need it not to respond touches

Comment: @Ric Perrott, i like your solution. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

In that case one work around can be used. You have to make a view that mask the textfield's text area but not clear button like this

We suppose that

```
someFrame = (20,50,100,44)
```

And textfield button around `20*20`

So our view will be

```
UIView *maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (20,50,80,44)]; 
maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Add this view after your textfield added. And it will mask textfield's that area which used for text and leave button area as it is.

Remember, this is not tested and just a work around. So any other method is there than I recommend to you to use that. And change value according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading a cell from the nib or else. I have just tried to make my own custom cell like below
[image]

Assigning tag ( it is 9 in my sample ) for the uitextfield

In `viewForCellAtIndex` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell ;

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"purchaseNibCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PurchaseNibCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell                    =   self.purchaseCell;
            self.purchaseCell       =   nil;

        }
        UITextField *text           =   (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:9];
        text.enabled                =   NO; <------ if you have not done in the xib file.
        cell.backgroundView         =   [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
        UIImageView *accessoryView  =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory.png"]];
        cell.accessoryView          =   accessoryView;

    return cell;
}
```

hope it helps